# Valid resolve causes catch with wrong output

Tags: typescript, promise

Im using es5, commonjs, use strict and have set noImplicitAny to false. I have a problem where when calling the grabUser() function to get information from a user in a database. It returns me with a `catch((err: any) => {})` where `err` is expected to contain some sort of error message. However `err` includes all the that correct data that should have been passed as result to `then((result: any) => {})`.

The output I get is `content err` which indicates that it has been passed to the catch, with all the resultdata from the database that I want to use.

My question is why the script resolves the request, but still catches as it would have been an error. But contains the information from the database that I'm looking to use, as if it would have been continued to `then()`?

```
class Database {

  connection: any;
  options: any = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PWD,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME
  };

  constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createConnection(this.options);
  }

  query(sql: string, args: any) {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      this.connection.query(sql, args, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Query Error")
          return reject(err);
        }
        else {
          console.log("Query Succsess")
          resolve(rows);
        }
      });
    });
  }

  close() {
    return new Promise((reject, resolve) => {
      this.connection.end((err) => {
        if (err)
            return reject(err);
        else
            resolve();
      });
    });
  }

}

export async function grabUser(item: string, discord: any)
{
    var Con = new Database();

    // checks if there is a user with the uID in the Database with discord.id
    return Con.query(`select ${item} from users where uID = ?`, [discord.id])
        .then((result: any) => {
          Con.close();
          console.log("content result")
          console.log(result)
          console.log("length")
          console.log(result.length)
          console.log("type")
          console.log(typeof result)
          // If there is something that it returned and that its larger than 0
          if (result && result.length > 0)
            return result[0];
          else
            return false;
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log("content err")
          console.log(err)
          console.log("length")
          console.log(err.length)
          console.log("type")
          console.log(typeof err)
          // log(err);
          return false;
        });
}
```

Comment: resolve is the first param. You are calling it reject and vice versa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up `resolve` and `reject` params.
It should be like this:

```js
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
}
```